# Enable local network users to access WAMP sites, but except localhost page

Tags: server, localhost, wamp

I put my WAMP sites on a virtual server and from there I want everybody connected to a VPN to have access to it.

If my server's IP address is 172.13.12.156, after choosing the option Put Online in WAMP, I can access one of the sites like this:

http://172.13.12.156/mysite/

The problem is that I would want to remove access when someone types just:

http://172.13.12.156

so that they won't be able to see the WAMP panel.

Is this possible?

ADDITIONAL INFO

At this moment I have tried:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/"> 
    Order Deny,Allow 
    Deny from all 
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 
</Directory> 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/my_site1/"> 
    # There will be comments here and some options like FollowSymLinks and AllowOverride Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI 
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I am using WAMP Server 2.5.

Comment: At this moment I have tried:`<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/my_site1/">
    # There will be comments here and some options like FollowSymLinks and AllowOverride
   
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

Comment: Is that your attempt at an Apache - Virtual Host definition of have you done that in the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Yes, I wanted to grant access to my_site1 directory, but I can only access the index file in it. This is in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Sorry, is that coded in the `httpd.conf` file OR the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Comment: In the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Ok 2 minutes, working on an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124796/discussion-between-olivia-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMPServer 2.5 uses Apache 2.4

So first of all dont mix Apache 2.2 syntax with Apache 2.4 syntax (it confuses Apache very easily) in the same section. It is better to use just the new Apache 2.4 syntax anyway.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/"> 
    Require local
</Directory> 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/my_site1/"> 
    Require all granted 
    # plus any other Options etc that are required by this site
</Directory>
```