# href Link Stopped Working

Tags: php, html, href

I  have a href link that when clicked should open an Excel file located to that location. It worked perfectly in Chrome and IE9, but since yesterday it just stopped working, although nothing was changed.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
$file_name="MyFile.xlsx";
$folder_name="CurrentFolder" . "/";
$file_path='D:/AllFiles/';
$link1=$file_path. $folder_name. $file_name;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link1 ?>" target=_blank>
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%"> 
                <?php echo "$link1"; ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

Edit:

This is some of the httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Require local
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/site1/">
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

Alias "/ssfiles" "D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder"
<Directory "D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: So what does the final link look like in the browser? And what does your http servers access and error log files reveal when you click it? What does your browsers development console reveal for the request? And what does "stopped working" actually mean? What _exactly_ happens if you click it?

Comment: i think **D** change into **d**

Comment: Hi Olivia, I would guess that `D:/AllFiles/.....` is not within your DocumentRoot folder and is therefore not accessible to Apache.

Comment: @arkascha: It worked until then, as I have used this link for a few months, and each time I clicked it, it would open the Excel file I searched for. I looked into the console now and I have this error: _Not allowed to load local resource_ . But if I copy the link address and Paste it into My Computer, it opens my file.

Comment: You need a semi-colon after your first `echo` statement. PHP will be going nuts.

Comment: @jhmckimm Sorry, but that is not true, it is _not_ required.

Comment: @arkascha `Line : 3,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '' ?>` - Yes, it is.

Comment: Sounds like you run into the issue that for security reasons access to the client side local file system is blocked in todays browsers by such a direct access. The reasons are obvious. Most likely your browser has been updated in the mean time.

Comment: @jhmckimm No idea what that error is, where it comes from. Line 3 certainly is _not_ that echo statement. Apart from that: it is _not_ required. Just checked that again locally, just to be _really_ sure.

Comment: @arkascha Line 3 was my checking locally, but I'd fat fingered an extra `'` in by mistake. There goes my leading argument for using `<?= ?>` tags. Seems I've been mistaken all along.

Comment: @RiggsFolly:  I put `Options FollowSymLinks` in the httpd.conf file under the site's directory, but still no changes.

Comment: `FollowSymLinks` will only have an effect if you created a SYMLINK to that other folder inside DocumentRoot. i am guessing you didnt do that. Anyway its better at least on Windows and while you are learning to use an Alias as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

Because the `D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder` folder is outside the DocumentRoot folder Apache is not allowed access to it. By this I mean when the user clicks the link you have created Apache sees a folder that it has not been told is it allowed to access and does not have rights to access.

You need to create an Alias for folders stored outside the DocumentRoot so Apache know it is allowed to access them, and what they are called(alias) and who is allowed to request the data.

```
Alias "/ssfiles" "D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder"
<Directory "D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then change the code to use the alias you have created, then anything that apache see's being requested from `domain.tld/ssfiles/anyfilename.ext` it will attempt to server from `D:/AllFiles/CurrentFolder`

```
<?php
$spreadsheet_alias  = 'ssfiles/';
$file_name          = 'MyFile.xlsx';
$link1= $spreadsheet_alias. $file_name;
?>    
<a href="<?php echo $link1 ?>" target=_blank>
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%"> 
        <?php echo "$link1"; ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

PS: This may have happened because we fixed something from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787737/enable-local-network-users-to-access-wamp-sites-but-except-localhost-page)

Comment: I did the changes in httpd.conf and restarted Apache, but now Apache doesn't start back. I put the Alias section under the other Directory sections that I added the other day.

Comment: You had better show some of the `httpd.conf` add that area to your question

Comment: I think the problem is the path I am using doesn't exist on the Virtual Server. When I do `httpd.exe -t` in cmd on the server, I receive the Path Invalid error.